# How can i include an image created by GD on fly , to a php or phtml file?

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

How Can i include this image to my php or html file on fly by just 
putting an `<img src="<? echo $im?>"  />`

Is it possible without saving the image and giving the path.

Comment: You'd probably want to move the header() call to just before the imagepng() call - otherwise your 'die()' text will never get seen by the user - the browser'll think it's part of the PNG image and show the "corrupted image" icon since it's not valid PNG data.

Comment: You are better off saving it, and using a database table to keep track of them. You may not want to be doing image processing each time a user visits the particular page however because it is slow and uses a lot of memory. The more you can preprocess images like this and save them to the file system before the page request, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see would be to use [**data-URI**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), and to [`base64_encode()`](https://www.php.net/base64_encode) the content of your image into that ; which would get an `<img>` tag such as this one *(quoting [an example](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) from the wikipedia page I linked to)* :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

But note it will not work with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Helps to read the PHP Man pages, the comments provide some good information.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php#93393